# Satellite Imagery Tiles X Y Coords

Tags: mapbox

For raster tiles, like the satellite imagery, the files seem like they're stored by zoom level, and then x and y coordinate system with an origin at at -180, 90.

According to their [satellite imagery](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/satellite-imagery/) page, it seems like zoom levels range from 0 - 16 everywhere, and 21+ zoom levels in certain regions.

Is it possible to know what the max x and y tiles are at each of the zoom levels? And, given the same zoom level, would places closer to the equator have more x tiles than places closer to the poles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need some background information about the tiling scheme that Mapbox uses. OpenStreetMap wiki's [Slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) page answers these questions for you. It's the same tiling scheme used almost everywhere, although it doesn't seem to have a good name.

> Is it possible to know what the max x and y tiles are at each of the zoom levels?

For zoom z, the maximum X and Y tile is 2^z - 1.

> And, given the same zoom level, would places closer to the equator have more x tiles than places closer to the poles?

It's the other way around. There are the same number of tiles horizontally at the equator as near the poles. However, because near the poles, the geographic area is smaller, each tile contains a much smaller area. So, a given area is split into more tiles if it's near the pole than if it's near the equator.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed!